# Broken Windows 7 search from Music library folder

Tags: windows-7, search

I have my Windows 7 Music Library pointing (only) to my Music folder on my G: drive.
When I search my music folder from G:\Music I can find my music.
When I search it from Libraries->Music I get only partial results or no results whatsoever.
Why is this happening? This is sooo annoying!

BTW, the folder is also properly configured in Indexing options.

[image]